# What is an easy way to list the foreign key contraints in an MDB?

Tags: ms-access, foreign-keys

What is an easy way to list the foreign key contraints in an MDB?

Is there a system table that can be queried in order to list this information?

Specifically, I need to know whether any foreign key contraints exist in the MDB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the results of `select * from MSysRelationships`.

Comment: You should be able to select it directly in a new query

Comment: The response from the query is that I don't have read permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can examine the relationships collection of the database object:

```
  Public Sub PrintRelationships()
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim varItem2 As Variant

    For Each varItem In CurrentDb.Relations
      Debug.Print varItem.Name
      Debug.Print " " & varItem.Table
      Debug.Print " " & varItem.ForeignTable
      For Each varItem2 In varItem.Fields
        Debug.Print ": " & varItem2.Name
      Next varItem2
    Next varItem
  End Sub
```

There are other properties that might be of interest. Also, an [MS Knowledge Base article on copying relationships](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/129879?p=1) may give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = oConn.OpenSchema(adSchemaForeignKeys)
```

where oConn is ADODB.connection

Comment: This is useful when you can't get permissions